# Adding time-trends to entity fixed effects model

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am working with country-year panel data in R. There is an increasing trend for both my dependent variable and main independent variable with year. But, while my dependent variable is yearly changing data for each country-year, the main independent variable is changing with elections for each country. So it is usually a new value for every 4-5 years, but different years for each country since the elections are in different years.

To account for the time effect, I added a linear time trend variable to my regression using country (entity) fixed effects. But as I mentioned only my dependent variable is changing yearly, whereas the main independent (explanatory) variable is changing by "term".

Do you think adding a linear yearly time trend is a good idea? or am I capturing the change in my dependent variable only by this time trend variable? What would be your advice?

Thanks!